# Problem with morphedByMany and morphedByMany relation ship laravel

Tags: laravel-9, laravel-10

I have two Models of **products** and **attachables** Problem with morphedByMany and morphedByMany relationship Laravel is it is working with insertion when I try to fetch data using polymorphic I do not know why I am wrong.

**Product Model**

```
use HasFactory;

protected $fillable = [
    'name',
    'productUUID',
    'price',
    'sku' ,
    'length' ,
    'width' ,
    'location_id' ,
    'category_id' ,
    'remarks' ,
    'quantity' ,
    'status' ,
    'dateStocked' ,
    'invoiceRef' ,
    'sale_price',
    'description',
   ];

public function attachable()
   {
     return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Attachable', 'attachable');
   }
```

**Attachable Model**

```
use HasFactory;


protected $fillable = [
    'attachable_id',
    'attachable_type',
    'name',
    'datatype',
   ];

public function products()
{
    return $this->morphedByMany('App\Models\Products', 'attachable');
}
```

**Controller**

```
$product = Prodict::find(1);

return $product->attachable();
```

I tried to change relation return $this->morphToMany('App\Models\Attachable', 'product'); but it did not worked out

Comment: sorry it was morphToMany and morphByMany